# Marking state change alongside reaction in chemmacros

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros

I am working on beamer presentations for my students to discuss chemical reactions in my classes. I am using the following syntax for

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}           % Package for drawing
\usepackage{chemfig}        % Chemical Diagrams
\usepackage{chemmacros}     % For chemical reactions and symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{block}{Effect on equilibrium of \ch{NO}}
        \begin{reaction*}
            N2 \gas{} + O2 \gas{} <=>  2 NO \gas{} \qquad{} $\Delta H>0$
        \end{reaction*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that 0 is being shown in subscript while the intended output is regular-sized font. How to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163497/chemical-equation-with-heat-of-formation

Comment: @Guido, thanks for pointing out. I will edit my post and follow the guidelines you have suggested.

Comment: @cgnieder, the method you suggested worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `reaction` environment uses the `\ch` command from the [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula) package internally. In the manual of the latter one can read

> `chemformula` distinguishes between different types of input. These
>   different parts have to be separated with blanks [...] A blank in the
>   input *never* is a blank in the output. This role of the blank strictly
>   holds and disregarding it can have unexpected results and even lead to
>   errors.

Every blank in the input splits the input into different parts. In

```
\begin{reaction*}
N2 \gas{} + O2 \gas{} <=>  2 NO \gas{} \qquad $\Delta H > 0$
\end{reaction*}
```

we have the parts (remember that blanks after control sequences are ignored):

- `N2` (chemical formula)
- `\gas{}` (chemical formula)
- `+` (plus sign)
- `O2` (chemical formula)
- `\gas{}` (chemical formula)
- `<=>` (arrow)
- `2` (stoichiometric factor)
- `NO` (chemical formula)
- `\gas{}` (chemical formula)
- `\qquad $\Delta H` (chemical formula)
- `>` (chemical formula)
- `0$` (chemical formula)

Everything that cannot be interpreted as a certain input type (like *arrow*, ...) is treated as a chemical formula which means that digits are written as supscripts then...

In order to avoid this one can use `chemformula`'s math input type which must start and end with `$`. It also must be preceded with a blank and must not contain any blanks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\providecommand\IfChemCompatibilityTF[4]{#4}
\IfChemCompatibilityTF{>=}{5.0}{
  \usechemmodule{reactions,thermodynamics}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction*}
  N2 \gas{} + O2 \gas{} <=>  2 NO \gas{} \qquad{} $\Delta H>0$
\end{reaction*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second example has the input parts

- `N2` (chemical formula)
- `\gas{}` (chemical formula)
- `+` (plus sign)
- `O2` (chemical formula)
- `\gas{}` (chemical formula)
- `<=>` (arrow)
- `2` (stoichiometric factor)
- `NO` (chemical formula)
- `\gas{}` (chemical formula)
- `\qquad{}` (chemical formula)
- `$\Delta H>0$` (escaped math)

Comment: Interesting. What is the difference between `\qquad` and `\qquad{}`?

Comment: spaces after control sequences like `\qquad` are ignored, spaces after `}` are not. So `\qquad{}` ensures that the space token after it is recognized

Comment: Thank you. +1 since your answer is better than mine. Cheers :)